# filter an array with multiple values on same key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to dynamically generate a listview in jQuery. This works perfectly for the whole list, but now I need to filter/search/reduce my initial data:

```
var rezepte = [
{ "name" : "Eierkopf" , "zutaten" : ["Eier", "Zucker"] , "zubereitung" : "alles schön mischen." },
{ "name" : "Käseschnitte" , "zutaten" : ["Käse", "Brot", "Paprika"] , "zubereitung" : "Käse drauf und in den Ofen" },
{ "nme" : "Gemüse-Auflauf" , "zutaten" : ["Lauch"] , "zubereitung" : "1. schneiden 2. Kochen 3. essen" }
];
```

I would like to filter/search "recipe" by a searcharray like `var searcharray = ["Zucker", "Paprika"]` resulting in:

```
var result = [
{ "name" : "Eierkopf" , "zutaten" : ["Eier", "Zucker"] , "zubereitung" : "alles schön mischen." },
{ "name" : "Käseschnitte" , "Zutaten" : ["Käse", "Brot", "Paprika"] , "zubereitung" : "Käse drauf und in den Ofen" }];
```

I have tried a lot of things within the for loop: filter, map, push - but all without sucess always resuling in undefined objects.

I am also not sure what syntax my recipe Array should be: there must be the possibility of variable amount of "ingredients".

Any help and hint would be most appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Andi

Comment: Can you please show code which gives you undefined objects?

Comment: To clarify your question: You want those array entries where *at least one* entry of the array `search` is in the embedded array `ingredients` of the object?

Comment: @ Philipp: yes, exactly: where at least one entry of the array search is in ingredients.

Comment: @ FAngel: this is part of what I was trying: var result = [];
//var temp = [];
//$.each(searcharray, function(index, value) {
or
for (var i=0; i<searcharray.length; i++) {

result = rezepte.filter(function (rez) { return rez.zutaten == searcharray[i] });

}

//});
//for (var i=0;i<searcharray.length;i++) {
//temp = rezepte.filter(function (rez) { return rez.zutaten //searcharray[i].properties });
//result.push(temp);
//}

return result;

Comment: @FAngel currently no issue with undefined objects - I am not even there yet :-) See updated question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rezepte = [
{ "name" : "Eierkopf" , "zutaten" : ["Eier", "Zucker"] , "zubereitung" : "alles schön mischen." },
{ "name" : "Käseschnitte" , "zutaten" : ["Käse", "Brot", "Paprika"] , "zubereitung" : "Käse drauf und in den Ofen" },
{ "nme" : "Gemüse-Auflauf" , "zutaten" : ["Lauch"] , "zubereitung" : "1. schneiden 2. Kochen 3. essen" }
];

function search() {
    var search = $("#searchfield").val(); // returns string
    var searcharray = search.split(',');
    if (searcharray == "") {
        check = $.isArray(searcharray);
        alert(check); // true
        return rezepte;
    } else { 
        var result = [];
        alert("till here fine");
        result = $.grep(rezepte, function(rezept) {
            for (var i=0; i<searcharray.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray(searcharray[i], rezept.zutaten) != -1)
                    return true;
            } 
             return false;
        });
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;  
}
$(function(){
     $("#search").click(search);
})
```

I have it working with this code. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VcZtE/1/ (results could be seen in browser console). The only difference from your code is here:  `if ($.inArray(searcharray[i], rezept.zutaten) != -1)`. According to [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) for `inArray` needle should be a first parameter and array to search in - second. And you have it in opposite way: array is passed as a first param and needle (value to search for) as a second.

Comment: Great! Works perfectly in my jQuery project. Issue solved and learnd a lot from all of you guys. Thank you very much. Cheers, Andi

Answer (score 3):

Using native Array functions, this should work:

```
result = recipes.filter(function(recipe) {
    return search.any(function(ingredient) {
        return recipe.ingredients.indexOf(ingredient) != -1;
    });
});
```

Using jQuery, it would be

```
result = $.grep(recipes, function(recipe) {
    for (var i=0; i<search.length; i++)
        if ($.inArray(recipe.ingredients, search[i]) != -1)
            return true;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You don't get the alert because the function `return`s right before it. Notice that `typeof []` is `"object"` because all javascript Arrays are objects, only for primitive values (strings, numbers, undefined...) you get other values. You can test whether an object is an array with [`isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) (cross-browser [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/)).

Comment: appreciate your assistance. Have updated the question and deleted the comments. The ones to FAngel was referring to what I tried earlier (obsolete). There is no issue with undefined objetcs anymore. Current problem is that I would like to implement the $.grep() you showed me. Thx, Andi

Comment: It seems good to me, but place the alert either before the for-loop or after the `$.grep`. If you don't get the correct search results, you also might adapt your `searcharray` creating, currently the words might contain whitespaces etc.